# Filtering users by companyName

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I was trying to get all users in my Azure Active Directory filtered by `companyName` filtering.

The call I used was

```
/v1.0/users?$select=id,mail,displayName,department&$filter=companyName%20eq%myComapny
```

but it is returning an error `BadRequest` .

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: hmmm it seems trying to filter companyName with "eq" fails for me also. but with an Request_UnsupportedQuery error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Dan said, for now filtering on companyname is not supported.

As a workaround, we can use Azure AD v2 powershell to filter it, like this:

```
Get-AzureADUser | ?{ $_.CompanyName -eq 'company' }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does the PowerShell command work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)

Answer (score 0):

Filtering on companyName is not supported.  Can you indicate the scenario for why you need to filter on companyName, please?

Comment: I have many dummy employees in my list . only attribute that can identify relevant active users is 'companyName'

Answer (score 0):

As per the recent update from microsoft docs [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/identity/blogs/microsoft-graph-advanced-queries-for-directory-objects-are-now-generally-available/)

We can filter on CompanyName and possibly others too by passing additional header information.

We need to pass :

Header **ConsistencyLevel = eventual**

[image]