# Schema Extensions : "Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'companyName' of resource 'User'."

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm currently building an application that requires me to retrieve users from the Graph API depending of a custom property, in that case, `extoe82ql2v_test/companyName` but so far, the API responded with `Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'companyName' of resource 'User'."`

**The request to retrieve the extension :**

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions?$filter=id eq 'extoe82ql2v_test'`

**The result :**

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#schemaExtensions",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "extoe82ql2v_test",
            "description": "Extend data for users",
            "targetTypes": [
                "User"
            ],
            "status": "InDevelopment",
            "owner": "d9a847ce-ca03-4779-88d6-c7e4f98297fe",
            "properties": [
                {
                    "name": "companyName",
                    "type": "String"
                },
                {
                    "name": "managerMail",
                    "type": "String"
                },
                {
                    "name": "arrivalDate",
                    "type": "DateTime"
                },
                {
                    "name": "expiryDate",
                    "type": "DateTime"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**The request to retrieve the users depending of `extoe82ql2v_test/companyName` :**

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=extoe82ql2v_test,givenName,surname,mail,mobilePhone,department,companyName,accountEnabled&$filter=extoe82ql2v_test/companyName eq 'test'`

**The result :**

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
        "message": "Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'companyName' of resource 'User'.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-07-24T20:46:51",
            "request-id": "639b8131-70dd-4436-b624-88167fe105eb"
        }
    }
}
```

**The same query with the Microsoft Graph .NET SDK :**

```
var res = await _graphClient.Users.Request()
    .Select($"extoe82ql2v_test,givenName,surname,mail,mobilePhone,department,companyName,accountEnabled")
    .Filter($"extoe82ql2v_test/companyName eq 'test'").GetAsync()
```

I don't understand what the issue is as I followed what the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-schema-groups#5-get-a-group-and-its-extension-data) said about filtering custom properties

Any help is greatly appreciated

**Edit** : Here is how  `$select` without a `$filter` looks like

**Request** :
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=givenName,surname,mail,mobilePhone,department,companyName,accountEnabled,extoe82ql2v_test`

**Response** :

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(givenName,surname,mail,mobilePhone,department,companyName,accountEnabled,extoe82ql2v_test)",
    "value": [
        {
            "givenName": "Antoine",
            "surname": "D",
            "mail": "antoine.d@contoso.com",
            "mobilePhone": null,
            "department": null,
            "companyName": null,
            "accountEnabled": true,
            "extoe82ql2v_test": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.ComplexExtensionValue",
                "expiryDate": "2020-12-31T00:00:00Z",
                "arrivalDate": "2020-07-22T00:00:00Z",
                "managerMail": "antoine.d@contoso.com",
                "companyName": "test"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Edit 2**:
I successfully filtered the users with another custom attributes, `extoe82ql2v_test/managerMail`, it's progress but I still need to apply a filter on `extoe82ql2v_test/companyName` and make it works

**Edit 3**:
Filtering on `extoe82ql2v_test/expiryDate` and `extoe82ql2v_test/arrivalDate` also works, both of these attributes are useless to filter but at least I know they work. As for `extoe82ql2v_test/companyName`, I wonder if it is because this attribute exists in both the schema extensions and the `User` Graph object ?

Comment: Are you still looking for any help on this question

Comment: Hello @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity I'm still looking for an answer rather than getting help because I'm curious and the project has been completed. Filtering on this custom property was descoped from the project I was working on and the property has since changed its name `companyName` => `company`

Comment: Please try this `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=adatumisv_courses/name eq 'test'&$select=givenName,surname,mail,mobilePhone,department,companyName,accountEnabled,adatumisv_courses` let us know if it helps

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same problem and made it work by adding "$count=true" in the query parameters.

I also noticed it seems to need **ConsistencyLevel=eventual** in the request header.

For example:

- `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=CompanyName eq 'xxxx'&$select=id,displayName,CompanyName`

> Bad Request - 400 - 146ms

```json
{
 "error": {
   "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
   "message": "Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'companyName' of resource 'User'.",
   ...
}
```

- `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$filter=CompanyName eq 'xxxx'&$select=id,displayName,CompanyName` (with header ConsistencyLevel=eventual)

> OK - 200 - 404ms

\o/

(I got the hint by looking at this question [Microsoft Graph API cannot filter /users by companyName?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/280408/microsoft-graph-api-cannot-filter-users-by-company-2.html))

Comment: still getting
Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'companyName' of resource 'User'.

Comment: @Sven did you find a solution to this? I'm also adding in count=true but same error..

Comment: @EyeSeeSharp no, sadly I didn't

Comment: @Sven I just found my answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47091291/filtering-users-by-companyname 
had to add the headers mentioned there

Comment: @EyeSeeSharp is it the header I mentionned? (ConsitencyLevel)
If so, would it be possible to accept my answer? :)

Comment: @devpro  I can't accept answer as I didn't ask the question, but I did upvote it